# Scraping data displayed when moving the mouse over a plot

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am interested in automating scraping from webpages like https://www.hltv.org/team/7532/big. More precisely I would like to extract dates and #ranking from boxes displayed when you hang your mouse along the plot  (see screenshot below)

I tried to use python combined with selenium but I don't really know how to proceed further although I went through different tutorials. I feel I need to change top and left value from style attribute but I don't know how to do it and whether I should use xpath, css selector or anything else. Here is a piece of my code which returns the WebElement I am interested in (presumably) but I didn't manage to extract anything from it :(

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
executable_path=r'C:/Users/fabbe/Documents/Python Scripts/hltv/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.hltv.org/team/7532/big")

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='fusioncharts-tooltip-element']")
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8NkW.png)

Comment: If you are using FusionCharts, you can use their API events to fetch the values when you hover on the data plot, you can use dataPlotRollOver event, here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/w5tcppk8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take another approach to get the graph data, by that way you don't have to hover your mouse on all the parts of the graph.

You have to add the below imports.

```
import json
from lxml import html
```

**Code:**

```
url = "https://www.hltv.org/team/7532/BIG"
driver.get(url)
graph_data  = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.chart-container.core-chart-container .border-box .graph').get_attribute('data-fusionchart-config')
graph_text = json.loads(graph_data)['dataSource']['dataset'][0]['data']
for graph_item in graph_text:
    tree = html.fromstring(graph_item['tooltext'])
    print("Date:" + tree.xpath("//div[@class='subtitle']//text()")[0])
    print("Rank:" + tree.xpath("(//div[@class='ranking-development-top-info']//div[@class='title'])[2]//text()")[0])
driver.close()
```

Here are getting the graph content and then parsing it. Then get only data that we are interested in and iterate through all the graph items.

Below is the the output.

```
Date:24th December 2018
Rank:#11
Date:31st December 2018
Rank:#11
Date:7th January 2019
Rank:#11
Date:14th January 2019
Rank:#12
Date:21st January 2019
Rank:#13
Date:28th January 2019
Rank:#13
Date:4th February 2019
Rank:#15
Date:11th February 2019
Rank:#12
Date:18th February 2019
Rank:#14
Date:25th February 2019
Rank:#15
Date:4th March 2019
Rank:#18
Date:11th March 2019
Rank:#16
Date:18th March 2019
Rank:#18
Date:25th March 2019
Rank:#18
Date:1st April 2019
Rank:#18
Date:8th April 2019
Rank:#18
Date:15th April 2019
Rank:#18
Date:22nd April 2019
Rank:#19
Date:29th April 2019
Rank:#19
Date:6th May 2019
Rank:#18
Date:13th May 2019
Rank:#18
Date:20th May 2019
Rank:#20
Date:27th May 2019
Rank:#22
Date:3rd June 2019
Rank:#22
Date:10th June 2019
Rank:#22
Date:17th June 2019
Rank:#26
Date:24th June 2019
Rank:#30
Date:1st July 2019
Rank:#34
Date:8th July 2019
Rank:#23
Date:15th July 2019
Rank:#27
Date:22nd July 2019
Rank:#22
Date:29th July 2019
Rank:#23
Date:5th August 2019
Rank:#28
Date:12th August 2019
Rank:#25
Date:19th August 2019
Rank:#24
Date:26th August 2019
Rank:#26
Date:2nd September 2019
Rank:#28
Date:9th September 2019
Rank:#24
Date:16th September 2019
Rank:#22
Date:23rd September 2019
Rank:#22
Date:30th September 2019
Rank:#21
Date:7th October 2019
Rank:#27
Date:14th October 2019
Rank:#24
Date:21st October 2019
Rank:#26
Date:28th October 2019
Rank:#24
Date:4th November 2019
Rank:#24
Date:11th November 2019
Rank:#24
Date:18th November 2019
Rank:#28
Date:25th November 2019
Rank:#26
Date:2nd December 2019
Rank:#26
Date:9th December 2019
Rank:#29
Date:16th December 2019
Rank:#33
Date:23rd December 2019
Rank:#40
Date:30th December 2019
Rank:#39
Date:6th January 2020
Rank:#46
Date:13th January 2020
Rank:#46
Date:20th January 2020
Rank:#46
Date:27th January 2020
Rank:#22
Date:3rd February 2020
Rank:#22
Date:10th February 2020
Rank:#23
Date:17th February 2020
Rank:#25
Date:24th February 2020
Rank:#26
Date:2nd March 2020
Rank:#21
Date:9th March 2020
Rank:#20
```